# Why position and momenta are fluctuating quantities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem

> In a coordinate basis we have
>
> $$\langle \Psi \mid \Psi \rangle = \int \prod_{i=1}^N d^3q_i |\Psi(\textbf{q}_1,\dots,\textbf{q}_N)|^2=1$$
>
> This means that for any quantum state $\mid \Psi \rangle$ the positions and momenta of the particles are not specified but are fluctuating quantities.

How is this so? As far as I can see its just normalising by integrating over all positions. I do not see how the fluctuation comment follows

Comment: Yes, unless $\Psi$ is a product of delta functions, this means the states do not have sharp position, and if $\Psi$ isn't a product of plane waves, they do not have sharp momentum. What exactly about that is unclear to you?

Comment: What is sharp position and sharp momentum? As far as I can see its just normalising by integrating over all positions. I do not see how the fluctuation comment follows.

Comment: "sharp" means they are eigenstates of the corresponding observable (and, ironically enough, these would not have finite norm). That the states are not sharp doesn't follow from this normalization condition, though, it is simply a consequence of the way quantum mechanical position and momentum work, so I have no idea what your question actually is.